# Error in the code Snippet

Tags: haskell

Can somebody please explain the error in the following snippet of code. in this code i have tried to implement the inorder traversal of BST while taking the input from the user

```
import System.IO

loop :: Int -> [Int] -> IO [Int]
loop 0 ls = return ls
loop n ls = do newNumber <- readLn
               loop (n-1) (newNumber:ls)

data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a ( Tree a) ( Tree a) deriving ( Show,Read, Eq)

singleton :: a -> Tree a 
singleton x = Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree

treeInsert :: ( Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
treeInsert x EmptyTree = singleton x
treeInsert x ( Node a left right)
                    | x==a = Node x left right
                    | x<a = Node a (treeInsert x left) right
                    | x>a = Node a left (treeInsert x right)

inorder :: Tree a -> [a]
inorder EmptyTree = []
inorder (Node a left right) = inorder left ++ [a] ++ inorder right

main = do
   putStrLn " Please enter the number"
   number <- readLn :: IO Int
   putStrLn $ "The num is:" ++ show number
   xs <- loop number []
   let numtree = foldr treeInsert EmptyTree xs
   print numtree
   ys <- inorder numtree
   print ys
```

the error i get is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO t0' with actual type `[a0]'
In the return type of a call of `inorder'
In a stmt of a 'do' expression: ys <- inorder numtree
In the expression:
  do { putStrLn " Please enter the number";
       number <- readLn :: IO Int;
         putStrLn $ "The num is:" ++ show number;
       xs <- loop number [];
       .... }
```

Comment: If the compiler gives you an error, add the error message to the question. If not, explain what you expect the code to do and what it actually does.

Comment: Please do not ask (nearly) the same question over and over again. What do you expect? SO is not a distributed compiler powered by humans. Could someone please close this question?

Answer (score 1):

Some problems I see with the code are:

1. You're calling a `loop` function that you did not define or import anywhere
2. You did not indent the contents of `main`
3. You write `ys <- inorder numtree`, which implies that `inorder` returns an `IO something`, but it does not. You should use `let` instead.
4. Your `do`-block ends with a `<-` assignemnt - it should end with an expression.

Comment: @user1145428: How do you expect us to answer if the code is incomplete and you won't even tell us what's wrong?

Comment: ok sorry everyone.. next time i will post the whole question clearly